# SQL. Count the variables through 2 another tables, using JOINS and COUNT functions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to count how many houses are on certain account where argument will be player id.

The important tables were presented on the image: [image]

As we can see, player has it's own account. The account can has more than 1 player, so I need to check all the players on the account if they have house or no. (1 player can has 1 house)

I want to create a SQL script that for certain player_id returns me the sum of the houses owned by players on account belonging to that player.

---

For example:
Player_1, belongs to account_1

There are 3 players on account_1:

- Player_1
- Player_2
- Player_3

The Player_3 and Player_1 are owners of some houses.

The function for Player_1 should return 2.

---

I had already done some JOIN's and edu up with

```
SELECT players.id AS Player_id, players.name AS Player_name, accounts.id AS 
Account_id, houses.id AS HouseID
FROM players
INNER JOIN accounts ON players.account_id=accounts.id

LEFT JOIN houses ON players.id=houses.owner

ORDER BY accounts.id ASC;
```

This has printed me, the nicely connected players with its accounts ids and the house id they own (NULL if not owner of a house)

I would like to get just a number of houses owned per whole account for certain player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first connect each player to his co-players (i.e. the players sharing the same accountId). Then, for each of the co-players, left join their houses (if any). Note that for each line, the house-id of the associated co-player will be `NULL` if this co-player does not own a house. Finally, its just about grouping by the player and count all the potential house-ids of his co-players:

```
SELECT p.id AS Player_id, count(h.id)
FROM players p join players co_players on p.account_id = co_players.account_id
     left join houses h on co_players.id = h.owner
group by p.id
```

Comment: I just modified it a bit that its giving me just the number for certain player id as argument with `SELECT count(h.id)` and `Where p.id = playerId`. Thanks, its great code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*)  
FROM houses  
LEFT JOIN players ON players.id = houses.owner  
Where players.id = { here put a player id without the curly braces }
```

Comment: It doesn't involve accounts, counts only for single player (1= has house, 0 = no)